# Global variable resets after exiting function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an extremely simple chat app but I got stuck on a weird javascript behavior.

Here's my code:

```
var msg = [];
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('chat_ajax.php?get=1', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key_i, val_i) {
        var node = [];
        $.each(val_i, function(key, val){
          node.push(val);
          //$('body').append('Test');
        });
        msg.push(node);
      });
    });
    for (var f=0;f<msg.length;f++){
        $('body').append('Test');
    }
  });
```

Note that this is included in a `<script>` tag just before `</body>` and the `?get=1` parameter is just for debugging

The thing is that the for loop doesn't get executed. After some debugging i found out that my `msg` array gets reset after exiting the $.getJSON() function (if I put the for loop inside it works)

It's probably some basic syntax error or my wrong understanding of javascript variables but I'm stuck on this for some time and my extensive googling didn't yield any results.

Comment: getJSON is asynchronous, that for loop belongs in the callback. It doesn't reset, it isn't set at the time that code is executed. Put alert calls and you'll see this :)

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, so Javascript won't wait for the response to come back before executing the `for` loop. It does execute, it just won't do anything because `msg.length` will be 0. Since your `for` loop depends on `msg` being filled, which happens in the callback, your `for` loop needs to be immediately after the `$.each`

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot about that. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getJSON` method completes asynchronously.  Hence the `for` loop is executed before the call back function which adds the values to `msg`.  You need to move the `for` loop into the call back.

```
var msg = [];
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('chat_ajax.php?get=1', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key_i, val_i) {
        var node = [];
        $.each(val_i, function(key, val){
          node.push(val);
          //$('body').append('Test');
        });
        msg.push(node);
      });

      for (var f=0;f<msg.length;f++){
        $('body').append('Test');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Oh god, in the heat of solving the problem I completely forgot about the fact that it is an asynchronous request... Thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm able to